# Как указать, что функция должна выполняться только один раз?

Tags: c++

Имеется некоторая экспортируемая функция some_init(). Нужно каким-то образом указать компилятору и/или линковщику, что функция должна вызываться однократно. При более чем одном вызове должна быть ошибка. Использовать глобальную переменную для этого, мягко говоря, глупо. Да и других причин против глобальных переменных хватает.

Comment: Прямо компилятору? В рантайме это делается тривиально. Во время компиляции — только если у конкретного компилятора есть соответствующий атрибут.

Comment: Это невозможно указать "компилятору или линковщику" т.к. вызываемость "один раз" - свойство исключительно времени выполнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда используйте статическую переменную. Это логичнее и нет выхода за пределы области видимости.

Как вы предполагаете, как можно *без сохранения в памяти* определить, первый это вызов или нет? так что ваше предубеждение против использования переменной излишне...

Тем более что когда вы это пишете сами - вы сможете выбрать способ сообщить об ошибке и обработать ее, а компилятор - имей он такую возможность - просто бы останавливал аварийно программу...

Comment: Про статику из головы вылетело.

Answer (score 3):

Для этого в стандартной библиотеке есть метод `std::call_once`, который обеспечит строго единичный вызов функции в потокобезопасной манере:

```
#include <mutex>

class whatever final
{
    private: static inline ::std::once_flag s_init_flag{};

    private: static inline auto
    some_init_impl(void)
    {
        ::std::cout << "init!" << ::std::endl;
    }

    public: static inline auto
    some_init(void)
    {
        ::std::call_once(s_init_flag, &some_init_impl);
    }
};
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yPybaYqeBg3FAYp9)

Answer (score 0):

Единственный, вроде, portable way — проверка в рантайме:

```
auto some_init() {
    static bool already_run = false;
    if(already_run) throw std::logic_error("Double init");
    already_run = true;
    return 42;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это очень просто в Lisp стиле. Пере-коннектите функцию. И никаких ифов!

```
// init.hpp
extern int (*someinit)(int);

// private.hpp
int privatesome_init(int);
int privateerrortwice(int);
int (*someinit)(int) = privatesome_init ;

// private.cpp
# include <iostream>
# include"private.hpp"
int privatesome_init(int){
  std::cout<<"Good boy."<<std::endl;
  someinit = privateerrortwice ; }

int privateerrortwice(int){
  std::cout<<"Again!"<<std::endl;}

// main.cpp
#include"init.hpp"
int main(){
  someinit(0);
  someinit(0);}
```

Результатом будет:

```
Good boy.
Again!
```